# Interface order of functions

Tags: solidity, mist, remix

I am creating a contract with the

```
function 1() function 2() function 3()
```

in a reasonable order. This order is in the "interface" created by the ethereum wallet or [solidity browser](https://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/) (for me) randomized.

Any idea how to get the interface to be ordered reasonable?

Comment: define 'reasonable' order.  I used ABIs quite extensively in the last few days to fix up some API issues with web3.js and I didn't care about order at all.  array.filter/find is quite fast compared to EVM execution.  Everything is named i.e. a json structure.  However I'm just guessing about what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order there is mostly unimportant tbh. Why does it matter whether they are ordered or not?

Comment: when there are hundreds of them, they are difficult to find